# Debugging PHP source code with gdb

Tags: php, debugging, nginx, gdb

I have a machine running a nginx server and PHP. I want to debug the PHP source code to see if the following function is invoked when I send the nginx server a http request.

```
static int multipart_buffer_headers(multipart_buffer *self, zend_llist *header TSRMLS_DC) {
   ...
}
```

I believe that one option is to run php-fpm with gdb. Is there an easier, more convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a good option.  Would probably be easiest to have php-fpm only spin up one worker process, so you don't have to figure out who got the request.

If what you're trying to figure out doesn't involve any nginx/php-fpm specific behavior, it may be easier to just debug via the built in webserver.

Comment: That you for the reply. Can you elaborate on using the built in web server?

Comment: Its been part of the CLI tool for a few versions now, the documentation can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php . You'd just start the webserver under gdb and debug that process

Comment: Thank you very much. Thisis very helpful

Comment: No problem, glad to help!